# Save table as xlsx file formatted based on a condition in R

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, openxlsx

I'm trying to save a table in excel with specific background colors for the cells that meet a condition.

#creating my dataset with 50 rows and 9 columns (each group of 3 columns should have only a given lot represented)

```
lot.name <- c("LotA","LotB","LotC")

set.seed(569336)
save.output <- vector()

for (i in 1:50){
  
  new.rw <-  sample(lot.name)
  save.output <- rbind(save.output, new.rw)

}

save.output <- as.data.frame(save.output)
row.names(save.output) <- NULL
colnames(save.output) <- c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3")
save.output$iter <- 1:dim(save.output)[1]
save.output2 <- save.output[, c(4,1:3)]
```

After creating the table, I want to export it to excel coloring the cells background as for example red for "LotA", blue for "LotB" and green for "LotC".I am trying to use the openxlsx Package and I have tried to change the background of the cells to red if they have "LotA" in the text:

```
##save output
library(openxlsx) #recall the library

wb <- createWorkbook() # create a workbook
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet", gridLines = TRUE) #add a worksheet to the workbook

writeData(wb, "Sheet", save.output2) # write my analysis into the worksheet of the workbook

## create style
RedStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "black",
                        numFmt = openxlsx_getOp("numFmt", "GENERAL"),
                        border = NULL,
                        borderColour = openxlsx_getOp("borderColour", "red"),
                        borderStyle = openxlsx_getOp("borderStyle", "thin"),
                        bgFill = "red")

# here search for the respective HEX color-code and assign a name to the style

conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet", cols = 1:ncol(save.output2),rows = 1:nrow(save.output2),
                      rule = "LotA", style = RedStyle, type = "contains")


saveWorkbook(wb, file = "RamdomizationExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

The issue is that R doesn't stop running and no file is created.

What am I doing wrong or is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Works alright for me

Comment: My R studio stops when I run the conditionalFormatting function and I can not even close R studio